# Generating proxy class from WSDL on the fly?

Tags: .net, wsdl

I'm currently working a Windows Service which when started takes a load of scripts and compiles them for running on a schedule, however some of these scripts need to access ASMX web services.

My preference would be to use these WSDL files in code to generate the .vb file ready for me to compile.

How could I achieve this without the command line?

Comment: 'without the command line' means programatically, without calling other external app?

Comment: What is wrong with calling ´wsdl.exe´?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont really get, why you dont want to use the native/legacy-Tools from CommandLine, but here you go:

```
var wsdlDescription = ServiceDescription.Read(YourWSDLFile);
      var wsdlImporter = new ServiceDescriptionImporter();
      wsdlImporter.ProtocolName = "Soap12"; //Might differ
      wsdlImporter.AddServiceDescription(wsdlDescription, null, null);
      wsdlImporter.Style = ServiceDescriptionImportStyle.Server;
      wsdlImporter.CodeGenerationOptions = System.Xml.Serialization.CodeGenerationOptions.GenerateProperties;
      var codeNamespace = new CodeNamespace();
      var codeUnit = new CodeCompileUnit();
      codeUnit.Namespaces.Add(codeNamespace);
      var importWarning = wsdlImporter.Import(codeNamespace, codeUnit);
      if (importWarning == 0) {
        var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        var stringWriter = new StringWriter(stringBuilder);
        var codeProvider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("Vb");
        codeProvider.GenerateCodeFromCompileUnit(codeUnit, stringWriter, new CodeGeneratorOptions());
        stringWriter.Close();
        File.WriteAllText(WhereYouWantYourClass, stringBuilder.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8);

      } else {

        Console.WriteLine(importWarning);

      }
```

**Note**

This is depending on `System.CodeDom` and `System.CodeDom.Compiler`
You can also generate a **c#** file by replacing `CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("Vb")` with `CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp")`
This Code is tested with [this WSDL](http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?WSDL) wich is pretty simple.